# Cannot get right slice bound for non-unique label when indexing data frame with python-pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such a data frame `df`:

```
a         b
10        2
3         1
0         0
0         4
....
# about 50,000+ rows
```

I wish to choose the `df[:5, 'a']`. But When I call `df.loc[:5, 'a']`, I got an error: `KeyError: 'Cannot get right slice bound for non-unique label: 5`. When I call `df.loc[5]`, the result contains 250 rows while there is just one when I use `df.iloc[5]`. Why does this thing happen and how can I index it properly? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error message is explained [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#non-monotonic-indexes-require-exact-matches): `if the index is not monotonic, then both slice bounds must be unique members of the index`.

The difference between `.loc` and `.iloc` is `label` vs `integer position` based indexing - [see docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing). `.loc` is intended to select individual `labels` or `slices` of labels. That's why `.loc[5]` selects all rows where the `index` has the value 250 (and the error is about a non-unique index). `iloc`, in contrast, select row number 5 (0-indexed). That's why you only get a single row, and the index value may or may not be `5`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 10):

To filter with non-unique indexs try something like this:
df.loc[(df.index>0)&(df.index<2)]

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the way you are addressing is that, there are multiple rows with index as 5. So the loc attribute does not know which one to pick. To know just do a df.loc[5] you will get number of rows with same index.
Either you can sort it using sort_index or you can first aggregate data based on index and then retrieve.
Hope this helps.