# Dask two conesquent concats result in a CancelledError

Tags: python, dask

I am getting an unexpected behavior after using concat two times on dataframes as follows:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]}), npartitions=4)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(10)}), npartitions=4)
ddf3 = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({'A': range(10), 'B': range(10)}), npartitions=4)

cc1 = dd.concat([ddf1, ddf2], interleave_partitions=True)
cc1.compute()  
# all is fine!

cc2 = dd.concat([cc1, ddf3], interleave_partitions=True)
cc2.compute() 
# KeyError: 'Cannot get left slice bound for non-unique label: 0'
# CancelledError : ('concat-indexed-8c92ebf8ac1bab2c09ee51c1da6ef22d', 0)
```

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a bug that must be reported?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot get right slice bound for non-unique label when indexing data frame with python-pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935294/cannot-get-right-slice-bound-for-non-unique-label-when-indexing-data-frame-with)

Comment: if the error is about non-unique index, why doesn't it appear after the first concat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that after a merge the index is lost. The solution is to `set_index` before the second concat.

A useful hint is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935294/cannot-get-right-slice-bound-for-non-unique-label-when-indexing-data-frame-with)